# Set permalink to Wordpress autopost

Tags: wordpress, post, permalinks

How to set a reasonable permalink on a post created programmatically using `wp_insert_post` in Wordpress?

The auto-generated permalink is http://home_url/year/month/.
All auto-generated posts created on the same date end up with the same permalink value.

Comment: Is `http://home_url/year/month` what your permalinks are set to within the WordPress dashboard? This could be why they are defaulting to that value. Perhaps changing that to another value? [Codex Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the permalink on a per-post basis but what I would recommend is changing your WordPress permalink settings to something like:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%
```

or remove day `/%year%/%monthnum%//%postname%`- Wordpress will add -1, -2, -3 if a title repeats

Aka the date and name based common option in the dashboard.

You can adjust this in the WP admin interface under Settings → Permalinks panel ( or Options → Permalinks before WordPress 2.5)

Reference documentation on the [Wordpress.org codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: thanks, Terri. I did that, and after sending my existing posts to Trash, Wordpress seems to have adjusted and now creates unique permalinks.